# Complex Array initialization in JNI

Tags: java, arrays, java-native-interface

Here is my java-code which i want to convert into JNI.
How can I do this type of stuff?

**Code :**

```
public class ArrayTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[][] a = new int[11][3];
    int[] b;

    for(int i = -5 ; i <=5; i++){
      b = a[i + 5];
      System.out.println(b.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You would create an `ObjectArray` where each element is an `IntArray`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but JNI's native functions are written in C or C++, right? [See here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: Also, [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) looks like it could help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, which logic contains in your code, but I just show you example how to create multidirectional array:

```
jclass intArrayClass = env->FindClass("[I");
// create outher array
jobjectArray a = env->NewObjectArray(11, intArrayClass, NULL);
// initialize inner array
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(imgArray, i, env->NewIntArray(3));

jintArray b;
for(int i = -5 ; i <=5; i++){
    b = (jintArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(a, i + 5);
    // print lenght of b array
}
```